# Dynogels: Query using OR comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels, dynogels

I am trying to optimise the following `scans` into a single `scan` (or `query`). The only way I see is to use to [use a `OR` comparator using DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275243/writing-dynamodb-or-condition-query). I am using `dynogels` (fork of `vogels`) in my application but sadly I am not aware of any `OR` query functionality in there.

```js
let arrivals = yield Reservation.scan()
  .where('room').equals(room)
  .where('arrival').between(from, to)
  .execAsync().then((reply) => reply.Items.map((item) => item.get()));

let departures = yield Reservation.scan()
  .where('room').equals(room)
  .where('departure').between(from, to)
  .execAsync().then((reply) => reply.Items.map((item) => item.get()));

let combined = arrivals.concat(departures);
return Promise.resolve(combined);
```

Proposed optimisation:

```js
return Reservation.scan()
  .where('room').equals(room)
  .where('arrival').between(from, to)
  .or.where('departure').between(from, to)
  .execAsync().then((reply) => reply.Items.map((item) => item.get()));
```

The scans get me the reservations that end (`departure`) or start (`arrival`) (or both) in a specified date range (`from`, `to`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be achieved using `filterexpression`.

**Sample code using filterexpression:-**

```
const scanItem = Reservation.scan().filterExpression('room = :idVal AND ((arrival BETWEEN :arrDateVal1 AND :arrDateVal2) OR (departure BETWEEN :depDateVal1 AND :depDateVal2)) ')
                .expressionAttributeValues({ ':idVal' : '2', ':arrDateVal1' : '21-APR-2017', ':arrDateVal2' : '23-APR-2017'
            ,':depDateVal1' : '21-APR-2017', ':depDateVal2' : '23-APR-2017'});                

scanItem.exec((err, result) => {if(!err) {console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined, 2))}});
```

**Note:-**

Not sure whether you wanted to specifically use `where` rather than `filterexpression` (or) just wanted to achieve the result regardless of `where` or `filterexpression`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out. Wasn't aware of the `filterExpression` syntax and just used the nice `dynogels` provided syntax.

Comment: I made a pull request to add this feature in, and im dependent on this feature so you might like it:
https://github.com/sp90/dynogels