# Use or and algorithm in dynamodb scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am currently using mongodb and plan to migrate to dynamodb.
I have a pretty complex algorithm to find elements implying AND and OR.

Here is an (simplified) example.
Search engine through users.
Let's imagine user has 2 fields: lastName and firstName.

A user search "Harry Po"

The search engine should search:

```
$or : [{$and : [{lastName : "harry"}, {firstName: "po"}]}, {$and : [{lastName : "Po"}, {firstName: "harry"}]}]
```

And we can imagine other stuff like having lastname "harry po" and no firstname etc

With mongoDB I am using java wrapper Spring DataMongoDB which allowed me to do pretty all the stuff I wanted to do.
However I am not able to find a way to do it with dynamodb

I found this page
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275243/writing-dynamodb-or-condition-query#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275243/writing-dynamodb-or-condition-query#_=_)

Howver it looks like I can only do an OR between my conditions.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You wrote: "I can only do an OR between my elements". What do you mean by "my elements"?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say conditions

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB you can specify scan condition that can contain AND and OR operators that combine expressions with operators like: >=, =, <, etc.

Here is what DynamoDB docs is saying about it:

> ComparisonOperator - A comparator for evaluating attributes. For
>   example, equals, greater than, less than, etc. The following
>   comparison operators are available: EQ | NE | LE | LT | GE | GT |
>   NOT_NULL | NULL | CONTAINS | NOT_CONTAINS | BEGINS_WITH | IN | BETWEEN

You can use a [ConditionalOperator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ConditionalOperator.html) to combine ComparisonOpertors:

A logical operator to apply to the conditions in a Expected, QueryFilter or ScanFilter map:

> AND - If all of the conditions evaluate to true, then the entire map
>   evaluates to true.
>
> OR - If at least one of the conditions evaluate to
>   true, then the entire map evaluates to true.
>
> If you omit ConditionalOperator, then AND is the default.