# how can i do this query on dynamoDB + Android

Tags: java, android, sql, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I've got a DynamoDB table containing 'n' Book title in only one dynamoDB Item (and this freak me out)

in this structure, rentBook is the table on dynamoDB, with 2 attributes:

```
String      StudentID 
StringSet   BookTitle // something like:["title1","title2","title3"]
```

In SQL I would have write something like that

```
SELECT StudentID
FROM   RentBook 
WHERE  BookTitle = "title1" OR BookTitle = "title2"
```

but with Dynamo i can't get the right results :(
anyone can help me?

**question 2:** Is this table structure appropriate when the number of rows increases?

Comment: What code did you try? Can you add this to your question?

Comment: You do know the difference between Android and Android Studio, right?

Comment: thanks you all for the edits... X_X
@petey i've tried this type of solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275243/writing-dynamodb-or-condition-query but dosen't works, got no results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ValueMap vm = new ValueMap().withString(":val1", "title1");
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("RentBook")
            .withFilterExpression("contains(BookTitle, :val1)")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(vm);
```